# Is this spam, link-only or correct answer?

Tags: discussion

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3576738/3545273) in Low Quality Queue.

It had already one comment showing that someone thought it was Not An Answer.

I wonder :

- should I flag it as SPAM, because it is self promotion ? But the author does indicates he belongs to the society so it should not fit in SO definition for spam
- should I recommend deletion as Link Only Answer ? But OP explicitely asked *Can ... or another technology be used* so isn't it an answer to that specific question ?

I ended asking to close the question as off topic because it is *asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library ...* but still do not know what should be done with that answer.

Comment: I consider such a not-an-answer spam. I could answer lots of questions with "I program for a living. Please contact me for an estimate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content of the answer:

> We (http://nexiwave.com) provide speech indexing SaaS solution. Please contact us if you are interested.

It is indeed spam:

> This answer is effectively **an advertisement with no disclosure**. It is not useful or relevant, but **promotional**.

The advertisement:

> We provide *<service>*.

And the promotion:

> contact us if you are interested.

When you encounter these posts (questions or answers), flag them as spam.

I also flagged the answer.

Comment: The "We" in the answer is hardly "with no disclosure", but otherwise I concur that it is spam.

Comment: I do agree it is an advertisement, but my doubt was coming from the **with no disclosure** part because of the "We" ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta don't let the disclosure part of it throw you off.  A post such of this with more blatent disclosure would still be spam because it effectively says "contact us and we'll sell you something to help".

Comment: @psubsee2003: Ok, but I think it could me more explicit in the definition of SPAM.